# ESP8266 to find all the devices in proximity

Tags: wireless-networking

Thanks for any help.
I am interested in knowing all the devices which are connected to and Access Point. I am using ESP8266 to find all the AP. But even after joining the AP, I can not find the all the devices which are connected to the AP.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are connected and have an IP address you can determine your subnet.  Once you have your subnet you can try pinging each device in turn to get a response.  However:

- This will show you devices on the subnet, not the AP, so could include more devices than you want
- Not all devices will respond to a ping.

There is no way of a device knowing what the AP has connected to it, unless you can programatically connect to the administrative interface of the access point, log in securely, and access its list of connected devices - all of which is too much work for most things.

So you have to then ask yourself if the solution to your problem that you have already decided upon is actually the right solution, and maybe if you asked us about the problem instead of the implementation of your (flawed) solution we could probably help you to come up with a much more reliable solution.

Maybe what you want to achieve could be done with multicast groups?  Or maybe mDNS (aka Zeroconf, Avavi or Bonjour)?